# SageMaker request_body is byte array instead of string

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I was wondering why the `request_body` that I'm passing in `predictor.predict()` turns into a byte array even though I'm passing a String. But, when I  pass the `request_body` through Postman by calling the SageMaker endpoint, `request_body` is a String.

So for instance if I do:

```
predictor.predict('"users": ["1"]')
```

And if I have my `input_fn` method as:

```
def input_fn(request_body, request_content_type):
    print(request_body)
    ...
```

The `print` statement would give this:

```
bytearray(b'\x93NUMPY\x01\x00v\x00{\'descr\': \'<U14\', \'fortran_order\': False, \'shape\': (), }\n{\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00u\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00:\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00[\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x00]\x00\x00\x00}\x00\x00\x00')
```

But I was expecting to get `'"users": ["1"]'`.

I get `'"users": ["1"]'` if I give the model this String through calling the SageMaker API endpoint in Postman though.

Answer (score 1):

Sagemaker needs serializer for the inputs being inferred.
For string, you don't need to give a serializer because there is already a default serializer IdentitySerializer present. I think Postman shows you a request body, not the serialized payloads

```
class sagemaker.predictor.Predictor(endpoint_name, sagemaker_session=None, serializer=<sagemaker.serializers.IdentitySerializer object>, deserializer=<sagemaker.deserializers.BytesDeserializer object>)
```

[sagemaker blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/preprocess-input-data-before-making-predictions-using-amazon-sagemaker-inference-pipelines-and-scikit-learn/)

[sagemaker dg](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-inference.html)

[readthedoc](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/predictors.html)

Comment: Isn't the _IdentitySerializer_ just suppose to return the same thing? Like If I pass "1", it should give me "1" back. But the serialized object its returning is a numpy array. And when I pass it in through Postman the same `request_body` is a string.

Comment: I guess postman shows you the string before it is serialized. `input_fn()` handles already serialized object inside the server

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I solved using the JSONSerializer.

```
predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
instance_type=INSTANCE_TYPE,
deserializer=sagemaker.deserializers.JSONDeserializer(),
serializer = sagemaker.serializers.JSONSerializer(),
endpoint_name=ENDPOINT_NAME)
```

I think the default serializer is in array